# How to execute code when I move from textbox to the next one in c#?

Tags: c#

in my program I'v made textboxs one of them is FileNo_txt ,so I want to check if that file number is exist in the database or not when I move to the other textbox ??

[image]

Comment: Have you ever check `Leave` event if it is winforms? And please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times..

Comment: is it winforms or webforms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void FileNo_txt_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     //check if that file number is exist in the database or not.

}
```

also add this line in your constructor(form Constructor)

```
this.FileNo_txt.Leave+= new System.EventHandler(this.FileNo_txt_Leave);
```

Comment: thanks for you it works

Answer (score 0):

**You need to subscribe with the `Leave` event of a Textbox.**

```
private void FileNo_txt_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //check if that file number is exist in the database or not

    //PatientName_txt.Focus(); if you want to automatically focus any textbox
}
```

**For more Information** [Try this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave(v=vs.110).aspx)